# How can I remove standard operation classes in Oro?

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

We have so called operations (actions) in Oro - forms and buttons that do some action. The problem is with styling of these buttons. We can add additions classes to them through yml, but we can't remove existing classes (like .operation-button class). Maybe there is actually a way to delete this standard classes?

```
operations:
    my_operation:
        button_options:
            class: btn btn--action-important
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `operation-button` class is define in the [OroActionBundle:Operation:button.html.twig](https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/ActionBundle/Resources/views/Operation/button.html.twig#L13) template.

It is recommended to update styles for the `operation-button` class to comply with your needs.

Or, you can define own template for the operation button:

```yaml
    operations:
        my_operation:
            button_options:
                class: btn btn--action-important
                template: MyActionBundle:Operation:button.html.twig
```

If you need to apply changes to all operation buttons you can override base template. See [Back-Office Customization Templates (Twig)](https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/back-office/templates/#override-twig-templates) in Developer Guide.